# Mirroring Filesystems without Transfers

Tags: files, filesystems, x-server, file-transfer

So here's my situation. I have a lot of files on  my local in 3 directories. I have a subset of those files + ~30 on a server in a more organized 10 directories. I'd like to move the files on the local machine to match their directory on the server (ideally I'd copy the ~30 additional at the same time but if not I can do that manually). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Okay let me illustrate. My local has files broken down like this in 3 directories:
[ A B .... F ] [ G H ... P ] [ Q R .... W ]

My server has
[ A B C ] [ D E F ] [ G H I J K ] [ L M N O P ] [ Q R ] [ S T U ] [ V W X Y Z]

I'd like to move the files I have locally into their corresponding local directory based on what directory they are in on the server (without transferring any files) [] is a directory, letter is a file.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me; `rsync` could come in handy.

Comment: @simlev I wrote an example to demonstrate the structure. I'm checking out rsync now.

Comment: Uhm..you could just mirror the server directory and files to the local filesystem, then search and delete any duplicate files in the local filesystem. If you don't want to transfer, you could save a list of files on the server, then programmatically check if a file is in the list and in a particular directory, then move it to that directory on the local filesystem. Is there any criteria for storing a file to a certain directory, other than it being on that directory on the server?

Comment: So is the first directory actually called `A B .... F`, or is this intended to show that some unnamed directory contains files whose names only begin with the letters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, or does it signify something else? Similarly, what does the server directory name `A B C` actually denote?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicate names among the files

1. obtain a list of files from the server (typically the output of `find`, relative to their common directory), and transfer it on the
   local
2. on the local, move all the files to the same directory (using `find [...] -exec mv -t some/staging/directory {} \;`
3. on the local, with the CWD as the common directory execute something like:

   ```
   while read f; 
   do
      mkdir -p $(dirname "$f")
      mv -v "some/staging/directory/$(basename $f)" "$f"
   done < files_on_server.lst
   ```